# Changing the default python in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: python, macos, macports, osx-mountain-lion

I installed Python through MacPorts, and then changed the path to that one.

`/opt/local/bin/python`

using this command

`sudo port select python python27`

But now i want to revert to the Mac one at this path

`/usr/bin/python`

How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT:**

I uninstalled the MacPort Python, restarted the terminal and everything went back to normal. Strange. But I sill don't know why/how.

Comment: what does your path look like?  `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sudo port select` command only switches what `/usr/local/bin/python` points to, and does not touch the `/usr/bin/python` path at all.

The `/usr/bin/python` executable is still the default Apple install. Your `$PATH` variable may still look in `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` though when you type in `python` at your Terminal prompt.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But then how can I make it use the `/usr/bin` path when i type `$ python`?

Comment: It will stop at the first one it finds when it searches your `PATH`. So simply move `/usr/bin` _before_ `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`.

Or, you can use [`pythonbrew`](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo port select python python27-apple
```

You can use `port select --list python` to list all python versions available via ports.

Comment: Yeah i did this, and all I got was `python27`, nothing else.

Comment: @Jose187 Hmm, what about `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python`?